# Is it possible to use the ICMP protocol with Azure Sphere Dev Kit?

Tags: c, icmp, azure-sphere

At the moment I'm developing a network monitoring with the Azure Sphere Dev Kit.

I'm using the MT3620 Dev Kit from Seeed.

My problem at the moment is that I want to use ICMP packets to create something like ping but I always get the message that the "Operation is not permitted".

I have read some articles and one said that Azure VMs block ICMP traffic (see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2014/06/22/use-port-pings-instead-of-icmp-to-test-azure-vm-connectivity/)).

So, my question is if it is possible to creaete and send ICMP packets with the Azure Sphere Dev Kit? Does anyone have experience with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ICMP (“ping”) is not supported. You can’t ping the device, nor can it send pings. You can open a Feature request for Azure Sphere team here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/915433-azure-sphere

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering the question! Now I have an answer and don't need to debug anymore. Do you have interesting sources where you found this? Thanks!